# Finite-volume method applied to a particular advection equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, simulation, finite-volume-method

I'm trying to apply the finite-volume method (FVM), with which I'm not so familiar, so a simple 1D PDE equation.

The equation I want to solve is, to simplify, 
$$\frac{\partial U}{\partial t} + A\left(x\right) \frac{\partial}{\partial 
x}\left(\frac{F(U)}{A(x)}\right) + \frac{\partial G(U)}{\partial x} = 0.$$

where $U$ is my unknown, $F$ and $G$ some flux functions computed from $U$ and $A$ a function of $x$, that is strictly positive and very smooth. Most of the time, I can actually assume $A$=constant, and therefore the equation becomes 
$$\frac{\partial U}{\partial t} + \frac{\partial(G(U)+F(U))}{\partial x} = 0,$$ which is straightforward to solve using FVM.

However, I'm not sure how to handle the case where $A$ is not constant. My idea was, when applying the integration step of the finite volume method, to write 
$$\int_{\text{cell}} A\left(x\right) \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\frac{F(U)}{A(x)}\right) \mathrm{d}\Omega \approx \bar{A} \int_{\text{cell}}  \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\frac{F(U)}{A(x)}\right) \mathrm{d}\Omega$$ where $\bar{A}$ is the mean value of $A$ over the considered cell. Once fully discretized, this term would therefore end up looking like

$$\bar{A}_{i} \left( \frac{1}{\Delta x} \left( \frac{F_{i+1/2}}{A_{i+1/2}}  - \frac{F_{i-1/2}}{A_{i-1/2}} \right) \right).$$

Does it make sense, or is it completely wrong? Is there a better way to proceed?

I tried changing the coordinate, but I'm not familiar enough with that, and of course I'd like to keep the $\dfrac{\partial G(U)}{\partial x}$ term as it is.

Thanks a lot for any inputs and advices on how to deal with this kind of problem.

Comment: This question looks like a great fit for http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Thank you, I also posted this question in  [scicomp](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/28794/finite-volume-method-applied-to-a-particular-advection-equation) following your advice.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it has received an answer at the scicomp site.